# How to get all dependencies of cloned repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, gitlab

I've just cloned a repo from Gitlab by **git clone ...** but when I am trying to run an application there's no required dependencies. How can I download all required dependencies for this project?

Comment: may be you should readme, package.json

Answer (score 7):

Make sure there is `package.json` in the root and also check for type of the lock file. If `package-lock.json` exists then you should do

```
npm install
```

otherwise if you find `yarn.lock` then you should do

```
yarn install
```

Comment: Considering that you have `Node.js` and `Yarn` installed and got both up and running

Answer (score 2):

Usually dependencies are installed in **node_modules** folder which is most of the time are ignored by git. If you take a look at the file named **.gitignore** you can see the following:

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
```

By applying this settings you are not committing to the repository the **node_modules** folder. A code repository intentionally should contain only the source code and the necessary configuration to run and install it locally. And that is the reason you need to install with the following command your application once cloning the repository locally:

```
npm install
```

This installation step will take a look at **package.json** file's dependencies attribute and creating **node_modules** folder where all the libraries will be installed. Once it has been finished successfully you can start the application locally. Look at the following example dependencies below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
}
```

From [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation:

> This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on. If the package has a package-lock or shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that, with an npm-shrinkwrap.json taking precedence if both files exist. See package-lock.json and npm-shrinkwrap.

If you are interested further in the topic, just read further in this article: 
 https://flaviocopes.com/should-commit-node-modules-git/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use  `npm install` if it is a javas app but make sure you first download nodejs from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download//)

Comment: By Javas you mean JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using npm you can just `npm i` or `yarn` in your terminal.
It will install all the dependencies you need.